# Atualizar os dados da consulta em php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Eu estive à procura em dezenas de tópicos, mas ainda não consegui encontrar uma solução.

Eu criei um formulário que mostra os dados da tabela da base de dados e quando os dados sáo alterados preciso de atualizar a linha da tabela.

**este é o código que tenho mas não faz o update na tabela:**

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <label>Insira a data:</label>
  <input name="data" type="date" placeholder="Type Here">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enter">
</form>
```

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['data']))
{

$servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');


    $inicio = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['data']);  


$sql = "SELECT `regOratorio`.`DataEntrada`,
    `regOratorio`.`Utente`,
    `regOratorio`.`Estado`,
    `regOratorio`.`Observacao`,
`InfoLuvas`.`Funcionario`
FROM `centrodb`.`regOratorio` LEFT OUTER JOIN `centrodb`.`InfoLuvas`

ON `centrodb`.`InfoLuvas`.`Id` = `centrodb`.`regOratorio`.`Colaborador` WHERE DataEntrada = '$inicio'";

 $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 if (!$result) {
      echo 'There are no results for your search';
  } else {
    // result to output the table
    echo '<form name="customer_details" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return alguma_funcao()">';    
  }

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{   
     echo "<fieldset>";
  echo "<table cellspacing='10'>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>";
  echo "<label>Data</label>"; 
  echo "<input type='date' id='DataEntrada' name='DataEntrada' value='".$row['DataEntrada']."'";
   echo "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
   echo "</fieldset>";

  echo "<fieldset>";
  echo "<table cellspacing='10'>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>";
  echo "<label>Utente</label>"; 
  echo "<input id='' type='text' value='".$row['Utente']."'";

  echo "<label>Estado</label>"; 
  echo "<input type='radio' id='Estado' name='Estado' value='Presente' " . ( ($row['Estado']=='Presente') ? 'checked' : '' ) ."> Presente";
  echo "<input type='radio' id='Estado' name='Estado' value='Ausente' " . ( ($row['Estado']=='Ausente') ? 'checked' : '' ) ."> Ausente";

  echo "<label>Observacão</label>"; 
  echo "<input type='text' id='Observacao' name='Observacao' value='".$row['Observacao']."'";
  echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
   echo "</fieldset>";

   echo "<fieldset>";
  echo "<table cellspacing='10'>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>";
  echo "<label>Colaborador</label>"; 
  echo "<input type='text' id='Funcionario' name='Funcionario' value='".$row['Funcionario']."'";
  echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
   echo "</fieldset>";

   echo "<input name='atualizar' type='submit' id='atualizar' value='Atualizar'>";
 }
echo "</form>";
}// end submitted

?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['atualizar']))
{

$data = $_POST['DataEntrada'];
$estado = $_POST['Estado'];
$observacao = $_POST['Observacao'];
$estadofinal = $_POST['EstadoFinal'];

echo $sql1 = "UPDATE regOratorio SET Estado = '$estado', Observacao = '$observacao', EstadoFinal = '$estadofinal' WHERE DataEntrada = '$data'";

if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE);

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Quando faço atualizar ele mostra estes dados dentro do `if(isset($_POST['atualizar']))`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já verificou se está entrando no `if(isset($_POST['atualizar']))`?

Comment: Como posso verificar, com o `echo`?

Comment: Sim, pode colocar um echo dentro do if, se não mostrar nada é porque não está entrando, logo, não vai atualizar.

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta o resultado de quando faço atualizar com o `echo` e penso que entra dentro do `if(isset($_POST['atualizar']))`, mas não atualiza os dados dentro da tabela

Comment: retire o echo... o echo serve para imprimir na tela

Comment: Retirei o `echo` mas não atualiza na mesma a linha da tabela

Comment: Atualiza em qual linha?

Comment: Expliquei mal acima, não atualiza nada na tabela em nenhuma linha

Comment: O problema pode estar no WHERE que não está achando a data. Qual é o tipo do campo `DataEntrada` na tabela?

Comment: É a chave primária

Comment: Mas é tipo date, datetime, varchar?

Comment: É tipo date, será esse o problema?

Comment: retirou o echo daqui né ? echo $sql1 ...

Comment: sim retirei....

Comment: Tem certeza que existe a data '2018-02-05' na tabela?

Comment: Sim existe...é a única linha que tenho na tabela

Comment: Não tem que executar a query $sql1 antes do if?

Comment: Não atualiza na mesma a linha da tabela

Answer (score -1):

O problema era a localização do `update`.

**Estrutura a funcionar:**

Primeiro o formulário para procurar a data que quer consultar:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <label>Insira a data:</label>
  <input name="data" type="date" placeholder="Type Here">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enter">
</form>
```

Depois  o método do `update`:

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['atualizar']))
{

$servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');

$data = $_POST['DataEntrada'];
$estado = $_POST['Estado'];
$observacao = $_POST['Observacao'];
$estadofinal = $_POST['EstadoFinal'];

$sql1 = "UPDATE teste SET Estado = '$estado', Observacao = '$observacao', EstadoFinal = '$estadofinal' WHERE DataEntrada = '$data'";

if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE);

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;



$conn->close();

}// end submitted

?>
```

Agora vem o método da consulta onde mostra os dados no formulário:

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['data']))
{

$servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');


    $inicio = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['data']);  


$sql = "SELECT `teste`.`Id`,
    `teste`.`DataEntrada`,
    `teste`.`Utente`,
    `teste`.`Estado`,
    `teste`.`Observacao`,
    `InfoLuvas`.`Funcionario`
FROM `centrodb`.`teste` LEFT OUTER JOIN `centrodb`.`InfoLuvas`

ON `centrodb`.`InfoLuvas`.`Id` = `centrodb`.`teste`.`Colaborador` WHERE DataEntrada = '$inicio'";

$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 if (!$result) {
      echo 'There are no results for your search';
  } else {
    // result to output the table
    echo '<form name="customer_details" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return alguma_funcao()">';    
  }

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{   
     echo "<fieldset>";
  echo "<table cellspacing='10'>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>";
   echo "<label>Número de Registo</label>"; 
  echo "<input type='text' id='Id' name='Id' value='".$row['Id']."'";
   echo "</td>";
   echo "<td>";
  echo "<label>Data</label>"; 
  echo "<input type='date' id='DataEntrada' name='DataEntrada' value='".$row['DataEntrada']."'";
   echo "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
   echo "</fieldset>";

  echo "<fieldset>";
  echo "<table cellspacing='10'>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>";
  echo "<label>Utente</label>"; 
  echo "<input id='' type='text' value='".$row['Utente']."'";

  echo "<label>Estado</label>"; 
  echo "<input type='radio' id='Estado' name='Estado' value='Presente' " . ( ($row['Estado']=='Presente') ? 'checked' : '' ) ."> Presente";
  echo "<input type='radio' id='Estado' name='Estado' value='Ausente' " . ( ($row['Estado']=='Ausente') ? 'checked' : '' ) ."> Ausente";

  echo "<label>Observacão</label>"; 
  echo "<input type='text' id='Observacao' name='Observacao' value='".$row['Observacao']."'";
  echo "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
   echo "</fieldset>";

   echo "<fieldset>";
  echo "<table cellspacing='10'>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>";
  echo "<label>Colaborador</label>"; 
  echo "<input type='text' id='Funcionario' name='Funcionario' value='".$row['Funcionario']."'";
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td>";
  echo "<label>Estado</label>"; 
  echo "<input type='radio' id='EstadoFinal' name='EstadoFinal' value='Concluído' " . ( ($row['EstadoFinal']=='Concluído') ? 'checked' : '' ) ."> Concluído";
   echo "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
   echo "</fieldset>";

   echo "<input name='atualizar' type='submit' id='atualizar' value='Atualizar'>";
 }
echo "</form>";

$conn->close();

}// end submitted

?>
```